# Отловить изменение input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Есть два `input`:

```html
<label for="disabledInput">Ваша дата приема</label>
<input class="form-control" name="Date" ng-change="change()" id="disabledInput" type="text" placeholder="Disabled input here..." disabled>

<label for="disabledInputTime">Ваше вермя приема</label>
<input class="form-control" name="Time" id="disabledInputTime" type="text" placeholder="Disabled input here..." disabled>
```

нужно сделать так, чтобы при смене даты поле время становилось пустым.

[Пример на codepen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bjjjxb?editors=101)

Пробовал через `cheng`,  но он помогает только когда ручками сам `input` меняешь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".btn-sample").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    document.getElementById('disabledInputTime').value = text;
});
$(".btne").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    document.getElementById('disabledInput').value = text;
    document.getElementById('disabledInputTime').value = ''; // Делает input времени пустым
});
```

Comment: а можно ли это реализовать через .change()?

Comment: Зачем вам `change()`? Он используется тогда, когда ввод сделан вручную, а у вас ручной ввод отключен.